# How to retrieve a Entity without Guid in Dynamics 365 SDK?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Well, I have this command: `IOrganizationService.Retrieve(String entityName, Guid ID, ColumnSet columnSet)` reference: [IOrganizationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx)

I tried the SDK Code Samples but the retrieve information is made using the Guid when this create a record, like here: `Guid _accountId = orgService.Create(account);`

I want to get this `Guid` using the name of the Account(Entity), how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `RetrieveMultiple` method & `QueryExpression` to achieve it. For example, the below [MSDN code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334688.aspx) is self explained to get the contact(s) with `lastname = “Brown”`

```
//  Query using ConditionExpression and FilterExpression
ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression();
condition1.AttributeName = "lastname";
condition1.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
condition1.Values.Add("Brown");            

FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression();
filter1.Conditions.Add(condition1);

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("firstname", "lastname");
query.Criteria.AddFilter(filter1);

EntityCollection result1 = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
Console.WriteLine();Console.WriteLine("Query using Query Expression with ConditionExpression and FilterExpression");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
foreach (var a in result1.Entities)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + a.Attributes["firstname"] + " " + a.Attributes["lastname"]);
}
```

> **Query expressions** are used in methods that retrieve more than one record, such as the **IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple** method, in messages that perform an operation on a result set specified by a query expression, such as BulkDeleteRequest and **when the ID for a specific record is not known**.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328300.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution using Query:

```
        //Query for the GUID of the Account using Account Name
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("account");
        string[] cols = { "accountid", "name" };
        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Account Name");
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols);
        var account = Service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        //Casting the reference to GUID
        Guid accountId = (Guid)account[0].Attributes["accountid"];
```

This will return the Guid information using the account name.

Comment: Glad you find it out yourself :)

Comment: You may also want to check out using the [GetAttributeValue](https://crmchap.co.uk/the-benefits-of-using-getattributevalue-to-access-crm-attributes-late-bound-c/) method. The last line could be: `var accountId = account.Entities.FirstOrDefault().GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid");`

Comment: or even `account[0].Id`

Answer (score 1):

Query Expression is one option. I find it to be the least efficient. Look for those methods that are more often used:

- Fetch Xml, queries are more efficient but are longer to develop. This is the prefered method to get count, sum or complicated criteras:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328332.aspx
- Early-Bound, queries are the fastest to develop and more user friendly but less efficient. This is the prefered method to get data with simple criteras like id or name:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328499.aspx